# Phonegap - HelloWorld app installed insted of "real" app

Tags: android, cordova

I run my phonegap app (`phonegap run`), but what I saw was a simple Hello World app.

In my project's directory I have files:

```
hooks/
platrofms/
plugins/
www/
config.xml
```

In `www` directory I have all files that are related to my app.
And when I `phonegap serve` I can see what I want under given address on a web browser.

I don't know wy on my smartphone I have only HelloWorld app with a blank screen, when launched. Could someone will be able to give me some tips, please?

Comment: On which platform you tested ?

Comment: On my device I have Android Lollipop.

Comment: Android platform added from terminal to your project ?

Comment: Can't remember now. Should I do something like: `phonegap build android` now? Or something that makes me sure about it now?

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Are you sure that your 'www/index.xml' has what you want for your app, and not simply a demo file with HelloWorld?

Answer (score 0):

Add platform Like this :

```
phonegap platform add android
```

in your project directory path using terminal.

Comment: It seems that it was added before:
`>>> phonegap platform add android  
npm  http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android

npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android

Platform android already added.`

Comment: then check your project www folders files and platform->android->assets->www folders files. Files need to be same. OR you can remove the android platform from project using phonegap platform rm android and re-add using above line.